# python subprocess.call() "no such file or directory"

Tags: python, subprocess, tcsh

I've found a few questions on the module but the more common problem seems to be getting the argument list right which I think I have managed (eventually)

I am trying to run a program that expects an input like this in the command line,

```
fits2ndf in out
```

with 'in' being the filepath of the file to be converted and 'out' being the path and filename to save the result to.

So using Subprocess,

```
subprocess.call(["fits2ndf","/media/tom_hdd/Transfer/reference.fits","/media/tom_hdd/Transfer/reference.sdf"])
```

this raises,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Setting `shell=TRUE` (which I know is bad) produces the same result. Not sure if it is relevant but I am using tcsh. Any suggestions?

---

Edit in response to questions

I haven't permanently set the PATH however `fits2ndf` is part of a package of programs which I initialize using

```
% tcsh
% setenv STARLINK_DIR  /home/tomq/star-kapuahi
% source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/login
% source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/cshrc
```

and normally works from within any directory without specifying the full path.

Comment: is `fits2ndf` in your path?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question, fits2ndf is contained in another directory but has run fine elsewhere without a full path, but it should not be part of the path to the .fits file.

Comment: @Karthik was referring to your PATH environment variable.  Is the directory that contains `fits2ndf` in your $PATH, and is PATH exported?

Comment: if you give full path of `fits2ndf` it should be OK. for ex: `/home/foo/fits2ndf`

Comment: Ok time to admit that I am very new to unix and get by by following tutorials and asking questions. fits2ndf is almost certainly not in my path. QUESTION EDITED as I cant format code down here properly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`which fits2ndf` will show you the path of fits2ndf.

After that you can write given full path to your code and it should work.

Ex:

```
~$ which mv
/bin/mv
```

My python code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["/bin/mv","/tmp/a","/tmp/b"])
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, is there away of getting it so I dont need to specify the full path to fits2ndf each time? In fact ideally so that I can use any of the programs within that folder without the path? It makes things pretty messy.

Comment: You can get the system `PATH` from `os.environ['PATH']` and modify it, then pass it in to `subprocess` in the `env` keyword parameter. Notice that `env` wants a dict; you might copy all of `os.environ` and modify the `PATH` in the copy, though commonly the subprocess you run doesn't require anything else to be set in the environment, and so it's sufficient to create a new dict with just the `PATH` member.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the space in `" /media/tom_hdd/Transfer/reference.sdf"`

Also, try tp put everything in one string, like `"fits2ndf /media/tom_hdd/Transfer/reference.fits /media/tom_hdd/Transfer/reference.sdf"`

Make sure you point to the exact direction.

Comment: good spot, thanks. Unfortunately that only appeared when writing this question and not in the code so it hasn't changed anything.